# Where Clause with Date in Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize as ORM for my Postgres database and I want to query something like "Select all, where date is between 22/10/2017 to 22/11/2017".

How can I do it with Sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `$between` :

```
where : {
    'created_at' : {$between: [your_startdate, your_enddate]
}
```